# How to properly design working hour schema for restaurants on MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, momentjs

I'm using MongoDB as my DB, and I wanted to have a working hour field for restaurants so that I can show if the restaurant is open or closed. This is the schema I went with:

```
workingHours: {
      type: [{ day: String, open: String, close: String }],
      default: [
        {
          day: "Monday",
          open: "08:00",
          close: "22:00",
        },
        {
          day: "Tuesday",
          open: "08:00",
          close: "22:00",
        },
        {
          day: "Wednesday",
          open: "08:00",
          close: "22:00",
        },
        {
          day: "Thursday",
          open: "08:00",
          close: "22:00",
        },
        {
          day: "Friday",
          open: "08:00",
          close: "22:00",
        },
        {
          day: "Saturday",
          open: "08:00",
          close: "22:00",
        },
        {
          day: "Sunday",
          open: "08:00",
          close: "22:00",
        },
      ],
    },
```

Then the query I wrote was to loop through the working hours and get the one with the day as the current one and then use moment to check if the current time was in the range of the open - close time specified.

```
let isOpen =false;
const day = moment().format("dddd").toLowerCase();

for (let i = 0; i < restaurant.workingHours.length; i++) {
        if (restaurant.workingHours[i].day.toLowerCase() == day) {
     
if (moment().isBetween(moment(restaurant.workingHours[i].open, "hh:mm"), moment(restaurant.workingHours[i].close, "hh:mm"), "minute", "[]")) {
                 isOpen = true;
                 break;
               }
}
```

Now, this works for restaurants that work on the daytime. Like 08:00 - 20:00. The problem is when the restaurant opens at 18:00 and works past midnight till 02:00. How do I take restaurants that work past midnight into consideration?

Comment: It's a very bad design to store date/time related values as (localized) strings. Better use week day number according to ISO-8601 (i.e. Monday = 1), it will save you many  cumbersome coding.

Comment: Define multiple opening hours, e.g. `[{day: 1, open: "18:00", close: "24:00"}, {day: 2, open: "00:00", close: "02:00"}, {day: 2, open: "08:00", close: "15:00"}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define multiple opening hours, e.g.

```
db.workingHours.insertMany([
   {
      open: { day: 1, hour: 8, minute: 0 },
      close: { day: 1, hour: 22, minute: 0 }
   },
   {
      open: { day: 2, hour: 8, minute: 0 },
      close: { day: 2, hour: 22, minute: 0 }
   },
   {
      open: { day: 3, hour: 8, minute: 0 },
      close: { day: 3, hour: 22, minute: 0 }
   },
   {
      open: { day: 4, hour: 8, minute: 0 },
      close: { day: 4, hour: 22, minute: 0 }
   },
   {
      open: { day: 5, hour: 8, minute: 0 },
      close: { day: 5, hour: 22, minute: 0 }
   },
   {
      open: { day: 6, hour: 8, minute: 0 },
      close: { day: 6, hour: 12, minute: 0 }
   },
   {
      open: { day: 6, hour: 18, minute: 0 },
      close: { day: 7, hour: 02, minute: 0 }
   },
   {
      open: { day: 7, hour: 12, minute: 0 },
      close: { day: 7, hour: 22, minute: 0 }
   }
])
```

Then you can easily create `Date` values from it and compare with other values.

```
db.workingHours.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         open: {
            $dateFromParts: {
               isoWeekYear: { $isoWeekYear: "$$NOW" }, isoWeek: { $isoWeek: "$$NOW" },
               isoDayOfWeek: "$open.day", hour: "$open.hour", minute: "$open.minute"
            }
         },
         close: {
            $dateFromParts: {
               isoWeekYear: { $isoWeekYear: "$$NOW" }, isoWeek: { $isoWeek: "$$NOW" },
               isoDayOfWeek: "$close.day", hour: "$close.hour", minute: "$close.minute"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $match: {
         open: { $lte: moment().toDate() },
         close: { $gt: moment().toDate() }
      }
   }
])
```

or

```
   {
      $match: {
         $expr: {
            $and: [
               { $gte: [moment().toDate(), "$open"] },
               { $lt: [moment().toDate(), "$close"] }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
```

which should be the same.